# ASP.NET mobile device registration

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, mobile, web

Thanks in advance for the valuable advice.

I am creating a mobile website here at work.  I am not new to development just new to mobile.  My original plan was to put a basic login (username/password).  However, I have been asked to create some sort of way to "register" a device that as to get around the username/password.

My questions are as follows:

Is creating this device registration scenario possible on mobile web?
If so, what is the best practice/method of implementing this?

Thanks for all the help.

-zd

Comment: Could you possibly use the devices IMEI and associate that with a user?  You could even have multiple devices "safe" devices associated with a user.

Comment: Maybe you can try this: http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/device.uuid.md.html#device.uuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to retrieve a way to perfectly identify a mobile user using asp.net.

Sorry.